# How to make a WMS GetFeatureInfo request in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to make a WMS GetFeatureInfo request using Leaflet. I can not find something in the documentation to describe this process. Can you please provide with an example demostraing how to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in support for that. See https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms.

Comment: So how exactly do u use this? I thought I should just download it and refer to the js file.