# I have these variables in Leaflet map .. my difficulty is in visualizing the information using a popup in the Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, getfeatureinfo

```
var ProvinciasWMS = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Mocambique/wms?',{
    layers:'Mocambique:Provincias_Moz',
  version: '1.1.0',
   transparent:'true',
   format: 'image/png',
   attribution: "myattribuition"
}).addTo(map);

var DistritosWMS = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Mocambique/wms?',{
    layers:'Mocambique:Distritos',
  version: '1.1.0',
   transparent:'true',
   format: 'image/png',
   attribution: "myattribuition"
}).addTo(map);

var PostosAdministraticosWMS = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Mocambique/wms?',{
    layers:'Mocambique:Moçambique_Distritos_e_Postos',
  // styles:'Provincias',
  version: '1.1.0',
   transparent:'true',
   format: 'image/png',
   attribution: "myattribuition"
}).addTo(map)
```

[image];

//I tried with this code, but the popup doesn't come out with information ... and it automatically downloads a file ... I don't know what the error is

```
map.addEventListener("click", onMapClick);
popup = new L.Popup({ maxWidth: 1000 });
function onMapClick(e) {
  var latlngStr = "(" + e.latlng.lat.toFixed(3) + ", " + e.latlng.lng.toFixed(3) + ")";
  var BBOX = map.getBounds()._southWest.lng + "," +
             map.getBounds()._southWest.lat + "," +
             map.getBounds()._northEast.lng + "," +
             map.getBounds()._northEast.lat;
  var WIDTH = map.getSize().x;
  var HEIGHT = map.getSize().y;
  var X = map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).x;
  var Y = map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).y;
  var URL = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Mocambique/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&LAYERS=" +
    "Mocambique:Provincias_Moz,Mocambique:Distritos,Mocambique:Moçambique_Distritos_e_Postos" +
    "&QUERY_LAYERS=" + "Mocambique:Provincias_Moz,Mocambique:Distritos,Mocambique:Moçambique_Distritos_e_Postos" +
    "&STYLES=&BBOX=" + BBOX +
    "&FEATURE_COUNT=5&HEIGHT=" + HEIGHT + "&WIDTH=" + WIDTH +
    "&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&INFO_FORMAT=text%2fhtml&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&X=" +
    X + "&Y=" + Y;
  popup.setLatLng(e.latlng);
  popup.setContent(
    "<iframe src='" + URL + "' width='400' height='200'         frameborder='0'></iframe>"
  );
  map.openPopup(popup);
}
```

Comment: Ah, the usual difficulties performing `GetFeatureInfo` WMS requests manually. I'm gonna point towards https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188951/how-to-make-a-wms-getfeatureinfo-request-in-leaflet - using that plugin instead of the Leaflet default image-only support should help things.

Comment: Please don't post the same question again. If you have additional info, edit the original question: [I need to view wms information through a popup in the leaflet map ... I tried to use this code but it doesn't work](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387685/i-need-to-view-wms-information-through-a-popup-in-the-leaflet-map-i-tried-to)

Comment: I can do a request for the information manually using code ... anything simpler that works for several layers, as in my case? if I have the code please

Comment: can you send me your email or any other address that i can use to send you?